# How to cast java.lang.reflect.Type to enum?

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I have fairly simple problem.
I have a variable of type java.lang.reflect.Type and I want to do two different things to it in case its holds class or enumeration. I can fairly simple check if the varaible is enum by simply asking `.isEnum()`. However to call the specific enumeration methods I need to cast this variable to be enumeration. Here is some code for illustration. I know it does not make much of a sence, but its just for the cast illustration:

```
public class TestClass {
    public static String text = "MySampleTextClass.";
}
public enum TestEnum {
    MySampleText
}
public class Tester {
    public static Object retrieveValue (java.lang.reflect.Type myVar, String enumStringValue) {
        String enumStringValue = "MySampleText";

        // the variable is enum!!!
        if (myVar.isEnum()) {
            return (Enum myVar).valueOf(enumStringValue);
        }
        // the variable is class!!!
        else {
            return myVar.getClass().getSimpleName();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried casts like

```
(java.lang.Enum myVar).valueOf(enumString);
```

or

```
(java.lang.Enum<?> myVar).valueOf(enumString);
```

but I can't make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Type` doesn't have `isEnum` method. Wouldn't it be simpler to use `Class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the static method `valueOf` that is declared in the abstract class `Enum`:

```
Class clazz = (Class) myVar;
if (clazz.isEnum()) {
    return Enum.valueOf(clazz, enumStringValue);
}
```

But ... a cast to Class is necessary as java.lang.reflect.Type is just a marker interface. Additionally, you must cast to the raw type Class to make it work. There are many runtime traps you can get into.

Overall, it's very uncummon to have such a requirement. Why do you have to use reflection for retrieving an enum value for which you even do not know the type?

Comment: You really should check if it's a `Class` object using `instanceof` before casting.

Comment: @Powerlord I think in general when using Reflection it's preferred to use `Class.isInstance(object)` over `instance of`.

Comment: @Powerlord: Yes, you are right. But this isn't the only problem with this code snippet. I didn't want to further comlicate it.

Comment: @JeffGohlke [`isInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) isn't a static method.

Comment: I agree with all your comments i wrote the code just to illustrate the casting idea as i explained above. BIG THANKS to Seelenvirtuose. This is exactly what I needed. SOLVED.

Comment: @Powerlord Sorry, that was supposed to be `Class.class.isInstance(object)`.  Makes more sense reading it when it's, say, `Integer.class.isInstance(object)`.